# How to upload a file, After opening it in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to upload file to server like citrix fileSharing present in App Store.

Using Url Schemes i am able to show my app in open with when the file is long pressed and copy it to the application

How to upload the file after it is copied to my application after "Open with.."?

```
                                    NSString *urlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://suremdm1jobs.s3.amazonaws.com/1210001/File%20Store/Shared/?X-Amz-Expires=126000&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIUWYTLGYBHPCWTNQ/20170426/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170426T060015Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=65b1dda18a96136d1bedd7c6da9bc8529b737370bb42f3328f24399763f48fbc"];

                                    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                                    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
                                    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

                                    [request addValue:@"7919" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Length"];
                                    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
                                    [request addValue:@"bytes 0-7918/7919" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Range"];


                                   NSMutableData *putData = [NSMutableData data];
                                    [putData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];


                                    // Append
                                    [request setHTTPBody:putData];


                                    NSError *err;
                                    NSURLResponse *response;

                                    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

                                    NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

What am I doing wrong. I always get a Unsupported Url error(-1002).

Comment: You got your string already encoded. E.g. a whitespace is "%20" in your NSURLString. might it be that the String is escaped once again, when you call [NSURL URLWithString:urlString] ? Thus your new url will be wrong. Can you log, how the NSURL looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Use it:

Configure the `AFURLSessionManager *uploadSession` as a `defaultSessionConfiguration`.
Setup the `NSMutableURLRequest` using method #2 above.
Use AFNetworking's `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:progress:completionHandler`:
`Bottomline: backgroundSessionConfiguration` does not work with streamed multi-part form and I could not get additional data to be included with `uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:`.